# Scrolling with mousewheel over an iframe fails in IE 8-11

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using al little jquery-script called Perfect-Scrollbar. So far so good but when i use it in combination with an iframe scrolling with the mousewheel fails in IE 8 - 11?

Firefox, Safari, Chrome or Opera are working fine.

In the  I am using this:

```
<link href="src/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="src/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
      <script src="src/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
      <style>
        .contentHolder {
              position: relative;
              margin: 0px auto;
              padding: 0px;
              width: 300px;
              height: 480px;
              overflow: hidden;
        }
        .contentHolder .content { 
              background:;); 
              width: 300px; 
              height: 500px; 
        }
        .spacer { 
              text-align:center 
        }
      </style>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $('#Default').perfectScrollbar();
      });
    </script>

And in the body: 

<div id="Default" class="contentHolder"><iframe src="test.php" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="1550px" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i get it to work in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think iFrame is the reason of your bug, and, of course, IE :)

Scrollbar appers when mouse is over, but iFrame blocks hover effect for parent content, the same for scroll event (which is handled by custom scrollbar).

Everything works fine if use native browser scrolling. So, try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) that uses native scrollbars behavior or any other jQuery scrollbar plugin that works so.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $('#default').scrollbar();
});
```

Working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/yh47j/1/